# cx_Oracle and ctypes issue

Tags: python, ctypes, cx-oracle

**Cross post from https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2607551 But no reply received after 3 days**

I have some code that works fine (using ctypes to call a dll), unless I run cx_Oracle first then I get an error:

"WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found"

An example of the code is below:

```
query = '''select * from table'''
cx_Oracle.makedsn(host="host", port=1111, service_name='service.name')
db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('/@somewhere')
cursor = db_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
db_conn.close()

lib_path = os.path.join("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\app", "data.dll")
self.externallib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
```

I am using python 2.7.5 on win7

If I comment out the cx_Oracle code it works fine OR if I run the ctypes code first.

Any thoughts appreciated,

Bevan

Edit:
The error message is occurring because a dependency dll could not be found.  I added the dependency dlls to my path and the issue is solved.  An additional solve could be to change the current directory to the location of the dlls

Comment: Are you mixing 64bit code with 32bit code?

Comment: Could you try with [this cx_Oracle alternative](https://github.com/lameiro/cx_oracle_on_ctypes) which also works on top of ctypes?

Comment: You might have an issue with loading dependent DLLs that's affected by changing the `PATH` environment variable or calling [`SetDllDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203). [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com) can help you inspect the problem.

Comment: @erny No everything is 32bit (as far as I am aware).  The dlls are 32 bit and my python enviro is 32bit.

Comment: @eryksun I have dependency walker but am unsure how to use it is this case.  There are a number other dlls which my 'data.dll' is calling they are all in the same location as 'data.dll'.  So I suspect and you are suggesting that cx_Oracle is changing the path or SetDllDirectory.  So when I call LoadLibrary with the explicit path it get to 'data.dll' but then it can't find the dependencies?  Any suggestions on how to fix

Comment: @erny re cx_Oracle alternative, I will try it after I try an idea about the path/directory.

Comment: Use its profiler on python.exe running your script. It can be configured to show all of the calls to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: @eryksun Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?  I have the code working now.  It was missing dependencies.

Comment: Please add an answer describing the problem cx_Oracle caused and your solution.